# Using Calibre to insert metadata for iTunes PDF books

Tags: itunes, metadata, ebook, tags, calibre

I'm looking for a quick way to add/edit metadata for PDF books. I'm hoping that there's already a program out there (I really don't want to write it myself) to search and insert metadata into PDF books. So far, my only lead was with Calibre. The main problem here is that it doesn't actually 'insert' the metadata into the PDF documents. Instead it creates a separate file for the metadata and a jpg file for the book cover. This is specifically for iTunes (as I use my iPad as an eReader). I would convert the books to ePub formats, but Calibre is very bad at doing this (especially for programming books) so I'm avoiding that. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this, it's a command line tool that can perform various manipulations of PDF files http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in the new versions of Calibre you can connect to iTunes.
This way you can manage (and edit metadata of the books) your ebooks in Calibre and synchronize the books to your iPad/iPhone using the Calibre software.

Just press the Connect button and choose the 'Connect to iTunes' option. I've got the Dutch version installed, so don't know the exact English texts, but I'm sure you can figure it out.